# Django ManyToMany relationship to queryset to pagination?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm, django-pagination

Here is the relevant code:

**models.py**

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    ...
    images = models.ManyToManyField('myapp.Image')

class Image(models.Model):
    ...
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name)
    body = models.TextField(blank=True)
    citation = models.URLField(blank=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def view_post(request, slug):
    ...
    dablog = Blog.objects.get(slug=slug)
    image_list = dablog.images.all()
    paginator = Paginator(image_list, 1)
    ...
```

In the admin I created one Blog object and two Image objects related to that blog. The code I posted above is only sending the first Image object to paginator and I can't figure out why. I know the rest of my paginator code and the template code work because if i change it to

```
image_list = Image.objects.all()
```

I can paginate through both images in the database. Please help this is driving me crazy

Comment: Hi! Could you show me all of your code, I am a bit unfamiliar to Paginator

Answer (score 0):

You defined paginator to only show one image

```
def view_post(request, slug):
    ...
    dablog = Blog.objects.get(slug=slug)
    image_list = dablog.images.all()
    paginator = Paginator(image_list, 2)
    ...
```

This, will show you two images.

Comment: No, I defined paginator to only show one image per page. The problem is that there is no "next" page when there should be

Comment: if you call `len(image_list)` what value do you get?

Comment: bro you're going the wrong direction. please reread it if you dont understand. especially the part that says image_list = dablog.images.all() only gives me one image when it should two while image_list = Image.objects.all() shows me i can paginate but does not give me the images i need

Comment: My answer my not be right, but as i can't see your images, i just wanted to make sure both images are coupled to your Blog-object. Because if you call `image_list = Image.objects.all()` you get them, so my guess is that one of your images isn't actually linked to your blog.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I'm thinking but I don't know what the problem in my model is.

Comment: Could you look in the table `myapp_blog_images`, maybe there's only one row there...

Comment: good call, myapp_blog_images only contains one row: id, image_id, blog_id, all of their values are 1 but myapp_image contains the two rows of values that i'm looking for. what's wrong with the model? its obviously broken but i dont know why

Comment: Something must have gone wrong uploading your image. You could manually enter the data in the database, or you can retry adding it in the admin. In your code is nothing wrong, however.